# Django :Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. Is it a django or javascript problem? how i can fix it?

Tags: javascript, django

how can use requier function in javascript enter the templates (Django)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in JavaScript because the require is not supported in native JavaScript for browsers. You can use the broserify or other similar solution to bundle your scripts from modern JavaScripts to be loaded in the browser.